# Mainboard seemingly has infinite power

Tags: motherboard, cmos

So I've played around with the OC settings on my mainboard (have done so quite a few times in the past). Only this time Windows locked up and didn't want to boot.

As is recommended, I've gone and done a CMOS clear.. or at least I tried to.
I unpluggged my PSU, turned it off in the back, took out the battery and.. that damn board still has power. There's 2 leds on there shining as if their life depended on it. It has been doing so for 18 hours now.
If I press the power or reset button nothing happens, so I can't clear the charge quicker (neither the button on the case nor the on the board directly).

I honestly don't know how to procede now. In order for a CMOS to work, the board needs to lose all charge. But it does not react to me pressing power buttons and it also won't boot.

Any ideas? Help and advice is GREATLY appreciated!

- Asus Z97-WS
- i7-4790k
- 32GB Kingston DDR3 2400 (running 2133)
- Corsair AX860 PSU
- EKWB custom watercooling loop

Comment: **Step 1**
Check sanity **Step 2**
Be sure NO device connected to the motherboard is connected to the PSU (like the GPU for example **Step 3**
Check sanity again **Step 4**
Try shorting out the caps on the motherboard **Step 5**
Perform exorcism and hope for the best

Comment: You should take a look at the [manual](https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z97WS/HelpDesk_Manual/), which tells you there is a "Clear CMOS" button on the motherboard that you should be pressing. Removing the battery is no longer a reliable reset method, since some motherboards now store firmware configuration data in non-volatile memory (nvram) that does not require power to maintain state. That said, you shouldn't still have those LEDs on either... hm.

Comment: Incidentally, can you identify *which* LEDs they are?

Comment: 1) I've pressed the Clear CMOS button. No reaction.
2) Well I have a few LEDs, turned all of them on, but the one that lit up on its own was the LED next to the 24-pin (the cable is disconnected right now)

Comment: Are there any cables still connected to the computer at all? Network, USB, anything? Did you try holding the clear button while powering the machine on?

Comment: Yes, I've only unplugged the wall power as well as all GPU cables, since I removed the GPU to get to the CMOS battery.

Network and USB are still connected. Yes, I have tried.

Comment: So to sum up, I guess:

Step 01: unplug every single cable from your PC

Step02: short the 24-pin on your PSU

Comment: I have to ask (and I'm not trying to be rude) but are you sure the lights are on and it's not just reflection from other light? If you turn the main lights off in the room (so you are in a dark room), does it confirm they're on?

Comment: Yes. Actually I have my room lights off most of the time. Also if a LED is red, it's pretty hard to confuse it with a default bulb light.
I've been building PCs for 8 years now, yet this scenario is new to me.

Comment: I'd suggest unplugging the rest, if only out of lack of other things to try.

Comment: Is this useful https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/why-do-my-led-lights-stay-on-even-when-the-switch-is-off

Comment: @Dave Thanks for trying, but considering it's on the motherboard, not an external LED strip, I have no idea how it is wired. And considering you can't unplug LED lights from the wall, but you can unplug your computer.. I can't make anything of it, Sorry.

Comment: Then external power is the only thing I  can think off (other than a phosphorescent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe seeing power coming from any number of devices which themselves have external power supplies.

Make sure you disconnect all USB devices, anything with batteries or it's own PSU (such as a powered hub) could accidentally be powering the motherboard just enough that it hasn't completely gone off.

Comment: And it was the one USB-cable I left connected. Shame on me : P

I didn't know USB-Power worked both ways. At least I learned something.
But it's kind of weird that just because of 1 USB device, the PC does not react to any buttons

Comment: From what I understand, USB power _shouldn't_ work both ways, but sometimes does... and causes very odd issues like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the possibility that you've damaged something, especially since in the comments you followed the manual directions and:

> I've pressed the Clear CMOS button. No reaction.

The power and LED light really is a red herring, the real problem is this.

ps. The network cables could theoretically be sending some power too (they can be modified to send power easily).